# Forcefully reformat USB drive

Tags: macos, finder, disk-utility, usb, monterey

I have a 64 GB USB3.0 thumb stick, totally empty, that was formatted according to Windows NTFS, but had some problem in its format (it kept freezing Windows programs that tried to read it in any way, e.g. just for storage capacity information).

I plugged it into my macbook, it was recognised, and I could look inside of its directory structure in Finder (but it was considered read-only). I used Disk Utility to "Erase" it (I think that's what to do to reformat). I chose "ExFAT" from the dropdown menu.

It was stuck on the first stage, "Unmounting", a cyclic progress bar, no progress reported, for 5 minutes. I just unplugged it. Now, plugging it back into my laptop, it doesn't show up in Disk Utility at all, nor Finder, nor `ls /Volumes`.

How can I forcefully reset the USB at this point?

Comment: In the Disk Utility "View" menu, is Show All Devices checked?

Comment: If Windows is having problems with it and it sounds like macOS is too, I would bet the drive is toast. Return it or toss it.

Comment: I second what @SteveChambers said. I wouldn't trust that drive under any circumstances!

Comment: For what a 64gb drive costs, unless your time is worth almost nothing, replace it and move on.